# What is the meaning of To Keep Tally

Tags: meaning, idioms, poetry

Here is a quot from Bloom's essay on Whitman:

> His knowledge and sexuality are one, and we need to ask: how does that
>   sexual self-knowing keep tally with the meaning of all things?

It refers to the following line of Whitman:

> My knowledge my live parts, it keeping tally with the meaning of all
>   things,

Now, what is the meaning of **keeping tally with something**? It seems it is idiomatic and doesn't relate to the meaning of tally as a record of a score.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to the second quote? Not knowing the original, it is hard to follow

Comment: Here is the whole stanza: "Come now I will not be tantalized, you conceive too much of articulation,
Do you not know O speech how the buds beneath you are folded?
Waiting in gloom, protected by frost,
The dirt receding before my prophetical screams,
I underlying causes to balance them at last,
My knowledge my live parts, it keeping tally with the meaning of all things,
Happiness, (which whoever hears me let him or her set out in search of this day.)"

Answer (score 2):

Tallying a sports score is just one sense.  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tally&ref=searchbar_searchhint) provides an explanation of all the senses:

> **tally** (n.)
>
> mid-15c., "stick marked with notches to indicate amount owed or paid,"
>   from Anglo-French tallie (early 14c., Old French taille "notch in a
>   piece of wood signifying a debt"), Anglo-Latin talea (late 12c.), from
>   Medieval Latin tallia, from Latin talea "a cutting, rod, stick" (see
>   tailor (n.), and compare sense history of score). Meaning "**a thing
>   that matches another**" first recorded 1650s, from practice of splitting
>   a tally lengthwise across the notches, debtor and creditor each
>   retaining one of the halves; the usual method of keeping accounts
>   [**to tally**] before writing became general (the size of the notches
>   varied with the amount). Sports sense of "a total score" is from 1856.
>   Also in 19c. British provincial verbal expression live tally, make a
>   tally bargain "live as husband and wife without marrying."

In this question, to tally is to record or keep a record of something.

Comment: The  "thing that matches another" seems to be a possible fit too given the quoted *with* and earlier *balance*

Comment: @lbf I read all of these stuff. Certainly your conclusion is totally wrong. I already have a better interpretation. Whitman here used “tally” as a noun but in the meaning of its verb: agree or correspond or match (check Oxford, Webster, or any other dictionaries). So Whitman means his knowledge keeps matching with the meaning of all things. But as I am not a native speaker I wanted to be sure about my understanding. Seems no one here has better idea than myself.

Comment: @Connoisseur This is exactly what it means. Or, more figuratively, keep up with. (But, essentially, one in one place is matched by one in another place.)

Answer (score 0):

Tallying is the sense representing equally sharing
For Example: Please tally the chocolates.